# Is there a utility that tracks most recently opened folders?

Tags: finder

Finder's "recents" feature is great, tracking most recently-opened files (from apps that report them to the OS). Is there a third-party app that keeps a running list of your most recently-opened folders?

Comment: Just being pragmatic here, I don’t think you’ll find one because it doesn’t seem practical.  Every file is in a folder somewhere and simply opening it traverses many folders.  Ex:  /Users/Documents/foo/bar/foobar.txt. Would this application remember every folder that you went to or the final one?  Another problem:  How would it know that was the “final” folder?

Answer (score 1):

[Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) can do that - amongst many other things.

It's one of the few utilities I think ought to have been part of the OS from the outset.

From their page…

> **Directory Assistant**   Access your recent, favorite, and open folders from DFX's toolbar. Hierarchical pop-up menus let you quickly
>   navigate through folders to get to your files.

Answer (score 0):

It's [Fresh's](https://ironicsoftware.com/fresh/) main purpose.  It doesn't do it especially well, in my experience.  It seems to get hella confused by non-human agents (other apps) accessing folders. But sure beats what Finder has to offer in that regard.